# Tensorflow method invoke() is very slow. How to speed up?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I use this model tflite: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/gjKv/Pjh7NxGsF

```
paths = 'venv/model_resnet.tflite'
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=paths)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
```

I start searching for the license plate frame of the car using this interpreter

```
image0 = cv2.imread(img_name1, 1)
image_height, image_width, _ = image0.shape
image = cv2.resize(image0, (1024, 1024))
image = image.astype(np.float32)

X_data1 = np.float32(image.reshape(1, 1024, 1024, 3))
input_index = (interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index'])
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], X_data1)

t0 = time.time()
interpreter.invoke()
t1 = time.time()
```

The invoke command takes about 10-12 seconds to execute. How can I increase the execution speed?

I tried to transfer code execution from cpu to gpu, the execution time even increased slightly.

Comment: You might want to share more details on the platform you are deploying to. TFLite mainly targets mobile devices not workstations

Comment: Can you check if the model is run on a single core or is distributed over multiple?  If you are using Linux the `htop` command can help you with that.